# how to left join a table onto itself n-times ? And if possible, with ZendDb?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, zend-framework, inner-join

I have a bit of a hard-to-explain (mysql) sql query question:

I have a database table, that stores the parameter values, and the case id the parameter values are associated with.

The foreign key is the parent_id, and each parent can have a variable number of parameters.

This means that if there are three parameters, there are three rows, four params, four rows, etc.

There can also be multiple entries for the same parent.  I need to compare the parameter VALUE for all of that parent's parameters, to get the case id.  The table is something like this:

table Case

```
id      param_value param_id parent_id caseID
----------------------------------------------
1       red          101         200     1234
2       pepper       102         200     1234
3       green        101         200     3456
4       pepper       102         200     3456
5       pink         205         250     9875
6       panther      206         250     9875
7       fuzzy        207         250     9875
```

This example above: there are two different types of parents:  200 and 250.
200 there are two sets for two case ids:

1234 : param 101 = red, and param 102 = pepper

3456 : param 101 = green and param 102 = pepper

The third parent is some other parent and happens to have three params (it could have even more!)

So I will know who the parent is, the param ids for that parent, and I will have the param values, and I need to find the corresponding case ID.

I could do this with two params with a select such as:

```
SELECT c1.caseId from case c1
INNER JOIN case c2 ON c1.caseId=c2.caseID
WHERE c1.param_id=101 and c1.param_value='red'
AND c2.param_id=102 and c1.param_value='pepper';
```

(this returns caseId = 1234)

but :

1. Using just SQL I cannot figure out how to do this with more than two inner joins (so I cannot make a similar request for the pink panther that has three params).  I need to know how to make the sql query with a variable number of params.
2. I can do this with the raw sql in zend, but if there is some way to do this with php Zend, then I am all ears!

Comment: MySQL has no in-built recursion, so options: 1. use a sproc 2. just join the table to itself as often as could possibly be required. 3. switch to nested sets. 4. handle the logic at the application level

Comment: Can one `parent_id` have multiple records with the same value of `param_id` ? For example: `red 101 , red 101 ` or mayby `red 101 , green 101 ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that there is a constraint in the `case` table:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (param_id, parent_id, caseID )
```

which means, that the table cannot contain duplicate rows with the same values of these three fields, for example the below situation cannot happen:

```
id      param_value param_id parent_id caseID
----------------------------------------------
1       red          101         200     1234
2       pepper       101         200     1234
```

then the below query could be used to retrieve `case id` for any number of parameters (below is an example for 2 parameters):

```
SELECT caseID
FROM cas
WHERE (param_id, param_value) IN
         ( 
            (101,'red'),
            (102,'pepper')
         )
GROUP BY caseID
-- a number 2 below - is a number of parameters pairs within the IN clause
HAVING count(distinct param_id) = 2
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f4e/4

Comment: Thank you, this works! I wonder if there's someway to do this within Zend, but if not I will use this!